# Adding logo to a chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

I would like, as a chat room owner, to be able to set a logo for the room.

Mockup of the final result, inside the room:

[image: logo for chat room]

Can of course also be displayed in the lobby, maybe as background of the room panel.

To prevent abuse and reduce risk of inappropriate usage, can be limited to only one logo per user (i.e. user won't be able to set logo for more than one room) and require 1000 reputation.

Comment: TBH, if you're an RO, and this is a feature you ought to be trusted to do this. That said, you'll probably would have to bring this up in the future, should chat development get some developer time ._.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek IIRC the rep requirement for being an RO is 100, which is a rep level I would still expect spammers at.

Comment: 100 rep spammers? Really? Someone's playing the long game then. Most get nuked pretty darned fast at 1 rep.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek voting rings do exist, sometimes they manage to reach pretty high before falling down.